# What is the difference between convert -unsharp and convert -adaptive-sharpen in ImageMagick

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I understand that the the `convert -unsharp` from ImageMagick is using [Unsharp Masking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsharp_masking) to sharpen the image. What kind of algorithm is behind `convert -adaptive-sharpen`? When I want to sharpen my lanscape images, which algorithm should I use? What are the advantages and disadvantages for the two algorithms?

Comment: Adaptive sharpening sharpen more near edges. Unsharp does not.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not an expert on the algorithm, but both operations achieve the same goal by creating a "mask" to scale the intensity of the sharpening. They differ on how the generate the "mask", and the arithmetic operations.

## With `-unsharp`

Given...

[image: original]

For demonstration, let's break this down into channels.

[image: channels]

Create a "mask" by applying a Gaussian blur.

[image: mask]

Apply the gain of the inverse mask if threshold applies.

[image: effect]

Ta-Da

[image: result]

## With `-adaptive-sharpen`

Given...

[image: original]

For demonstration, let's break this down into channels (again).

[image: channels]

Create "mask" by applying edge detection, and *then* Gaussian blur.

[image: mask]

Apply sharpen, but scale the intensity against the above mask.

[image: effect]

Fin

[image: result]

> Which command will give the better results for normal outdoor images?

That depends on the subject matter. It's a good rule-of-thumb to use `-adaptive-sharpen` if the image contains large empty space (sky, sea, grass, &etc), or bokeh/blurred background. Else `-unsharp` will work just fine.

Comment: Incredible answer! Thanks for this, really helped me to understand the difference.